# Can a chiral molecule be optically inactive?

Tags: chirality, optical-properties

Does there exist a chiral compound with zero optical activity? It seems possible that for some (chiral) arrangement of atoms, the optical activity of one section of the molecule could be exactly compensated by another section of the molecule, even if these two sections are not mirror images of each other. Although this is just a mathematical coincidence, does any chiral molecule have an optical activity of exactly zero?

Comment: Are you asking for compound with smallest specific rotation?

Comment: Edited it... I wanted to ask something else

Comment: It seems you're asking if _["a molecule with chiral centres can have zero optical activity?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meso_compound)_. But, I'm not sure.

Comment: I very much doubt that there is a compound with **exactly** zero activity. Meso compounds are achiral (by definition) even though they contain stereo centers.

Comment: @RahulVerma yes, but not just limited to chiral molecules that have chiral centres alone. There exist molecules without chiral centres that are chiral.

Comment: Do you mean allenes? they do have a stereocenter.

Comment: @Safdar allenes, spiro compounds, and combinations of rings and double bonds are a few examples

Comment: The likelihood of exact cancellation of optical rotation in a chiral molecule is extremely low, so much so that the answer to this question is practically no.

Comment: With infinite measurement precision then no, but within the limit of experimental error then yes - see [cryptochirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptochirality)

Answer (score 4):

The intent of the question appears to be to ask whether any chiral molecules could have *exactly* no optical activity. But this is problematic and the best we can do is test whether any compounds don't have *observable* optical activity.

As the Link by Nicolau Sater Neto to the concept of [crypto chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptochirality) shows, on this criterion the answer is **yes**. The molecule 5-ethyl-5-propylundecane shown here has no observable optical rotation even when a pure enantiomer is isolated.

[image: wikipedia image, creative commons licence]

One can intuit that the nature of the compound is such that its rotation probably exists but is very very small.

it seems improbable from first principles that non trivial examples (eg not meso compounds) exist where the optical rotation is *exactly* zero.

Comment: If the reason for the chirality were far from the center of chirality I would think the effect would approach zero or become not measurable.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, tertiary amines where all groups are different are optically inactive  (due to amine inversion) even though it's a chiral molecule. Eg. N(CH3)(C2H5)(H) or NHDT

Comment: While *technically* true this feels like a cheat as the *reason* why optical activity isn't observed is the lability of the molecules under normal conditions. At lower temperatures they might well show optical activity.